# Changing Response.Header makes javascript unresponsive on my page

Tags: asp.net, excel

I use

```
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.xls");
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

as a method to generate a CSV/Excel file in my page. 
It works like a charm, however, after I open the file, the scripts on my page are unresponsive; trying tie JS onclick on any component on my page dosen't work.

Any Ideas/suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

**The root cause is the Content Type.**

Javascript only works with certain combinations of ContentType ... of which 'js' itself must be a part. Try reverting ContentType dynamically to JS compatible type.